# Return column no based on Cumulative Sum in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel where i have to find when the target is exceeding the produced qty which is entered daily in separate column. I know the vba process but without vba is it possible?

[image]

The result is 4 for this case (image file). But Which calculation ishould use

Comment: This can be done is a helper row can be used.  In the helper row you would keep a running total.  you could then use a formula to identify when the running total exceeded your target value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: POC]

Seed your running total with your first value.  Assuming your data is layed out like the image above, place the following formula in D4:

```
=D3
```

Generate your running total.  In E4 place the following formula and copy it to the right as needed:

```
=D4+E3
```

Determine the column where the running total exceeds the target value in B3:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($D$4:$N$4)/($D$4:$N$4>=$B$3),1)
```

Now the above will return 7, but that is because that is the column in the spreadsheet where the criteria is met.  What you really want is the column in your chart where the criteria is met or exceeded.  in order to do that you need to subtract your data's column 0 position or subtract your data's column 1 position and add 1.  That can be done with the following:

```
Option 1
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($D$4:$N$4)/($D$4:$N$4>=$B$3),1)-COLUMN($C$3)

or

Option 2
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($D$4:$N$4)/($D$4:$N$4>=$B$3),1)-COLUMN($D$3)+1
```

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you. This just great. Thanks again for sharing your knowledge